# Fluent NHibernate Custom Access Strategy Naming Conventions

Tags: .net, vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map a Read Only property with Fluent NHibernate in VB.NET. But all the access strategies are reliant on the case sensitivity of C# (i.e. they want the same field name). But since VB.NET is case insensitive this will not work. So my next plan was to create a custom accessor strategy for Fluent NHibernate that looks for a field with the same name with an underscore prepended.

I haven't been able to find any documention on how to define this rule. So I'm looking for how to define a custom accessor rule for mapping, or any other alternative method that will get around this problem?

My property is setup like so:

```
Private _Test As String
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Test As String 
    Get
        Return _Test
    End Get
End Property
```

The only relevant access strategies that Fluent provides for this situation are:

```
ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField
ReadOnlyPropertyThroughLowerCaseField
ReadOnlyPropertyThroughPascalCaseField
```

But these all depend on the field being the same name as the property which is not possible in VB.NET. There is a chance that I may be missing something trivial about how these work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was unnecessary to use the access modifiers, or go through a field. I just had to map it as `ReadOnly` and it was able to automatically pick up the correct field to use when storing the data.

For some reason I was under the impression that `ReadOnly` would only make it so that the column would not be written to the database if it was set. But apparently it can also pick on properties marked as `ReadOnly` in VB.NET.

My final mapping for that field was just:

```
Map(Function(c) c.Test).ReadOnly()
```